# Display info from API to widget using OkHttp

Tags: java, android, android-widget, okhttp

I have such an OkHttp code to retreive data from OpenWeather API:

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    final Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(response.code() == 200) {
            Log.d("weather", "200");
            JSONArray array;
            try {
                JSONObject mObj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                array = mObj.getJSONArray("weather");
                widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.weatherTextView,  array.getJSONObject(0).getString("main"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    });
```

It's located in my Widget class in void updateWidget, which is called from onUpdate() void. But the problem is that this OkHttp code just doesn't get executed.
What can cause this problem?

Comment: `AsyncTask` is asynchronous -- the work being done there may happen well after your `onUpdate()` method returns. `AsyncTask` is also deprecated.

Comment: @CommonsWare what is the best way to call it synchronously?

Comment: Get rid of the `AsyncTask`. The rest is synchronous. Then, you will crash with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, because you need network I/O to be asynchronous. Generally, an `AppWidgetProvider` should not be doing network I/O at all. Use other things to do the network I/O (e.g., `WorkManager`) at appropriate times, and have them use `AppWidgetManager` to update the UI of the app widget.